# Volley not recieving http response but postman is

Tags: java, android, node.js, api, android-volley

I send the /getsms `GET` request to an API and I get the expected results on postman. However, when I try to make the same request through `volley in java` on `android studio`, it just doesn't get a `response`, I keep waiting and nothing happens.

I'm sure the API *does* get the request since the expected changes occur when `I send the data associated with the get request`.

So I'm at a loss as to why exactly it doesn't get a response.

Java code:

```java
    final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/myroute/getsms/"+frm;

    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String frm = response.getString("src_num");
                        String msg = response.getString("msg");
                        int id = response.getInt("id");
                        itemsAdapter.add(frm + ": " + msg);
                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception err) {
                        Log.d("excpetion", err.toString());
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
```

API code:

```js
router.get('/getsms/:dest_num', function (req, res) {
  console.log("get oldest unsent sms from db"); 

  let sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "dest_num=" + req.params.dest_num + " AND sent=FALSE " + "ORDER BY id " + "LIMIT 1;";
  console.log(sql);
  db.mycon.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log("SENT!")
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** So upon sifting through the logs I found this:

```
2020-01-15 22:07:23.481 11880-11880/com.example.sms D/Error.Response: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":4,"src_num":"321","dest_num":"1003435365","msg":"first message from server","time":100,"sent":0}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Apparently the response is received but `Volley` kicks when parsing. I cant see why this is happening. I don't see anything wrong with the JSON string. And is this really enough for it to not go into the `onResponse` function?

***UPDATE2:*** So apparently that was indeed the problem and what was sent wasn't a `JSONObject` but a `JSONArray`. and just needed to change the datatypes accordingly.

So the code ended working with:

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/myroute/getsms/" + frm;

JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response_arr) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = response_arr.getJSONObject(0);
            String frm = response.getString("src_num");
            String msg = response.getString("msg");
            int id = response.getInt("id");
            itemsAdapter.add(frm + ": " + msg);
        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println(err.toString());
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
    }
});
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Thanks to the comments for helping :)

Comment: Where in the java code do you "send the data associated" with the request?

Comment: The data I am referring to is the "frm" that is appended to the url. I use it as a parameter to do a query in the API code.

Comment: Right but do you see the changes in the backend when you execute this java code? Or only when you send it from postman?

Comment: Yes, the API prints the query result and the "SENT!" message in the console. So yes, it does execute the backend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try for The code given below and also add the request to the requestqueue of the new instance of RequestHandler.

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);  //here is the mistake of parsing which will be removed after it is converted to the json object
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0); //-----mistake
                        String frm = object.getString("src_num");
                        String msg = object.getString("msg");
                        int id = object.getInt("id");
                        itemsAdapter.add(frm + ": " + msg);
                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                           Log.d("excpetion", err.toString());
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         Log.d("Error.response", err.toString());
            }
        });

        new RequestHandler().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Hope it helps !!